# How to add scrollbars to TabItem?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I have the following method, which creates a `TabFolder` with two tabs (`TabItem`) inside it:

```
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Control control = super.createContents(parent);

    // 1. Create a TabFolder (dialogArea is a Control)
    TabFolder folder = new TabFolder((Composite) dialogArea, SWT.TOP);

    // 2. Create tab 1
    TabItem firstTab = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    firstTab.setText("Tab One");
    firstTab.setControl(createMyFirstComposite(folder));

    // 3. Create tab 2
    TabItem secondTab = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    secondTab.setText("Tab Two");
    secondTab.setControl(createMySecondComposite(folder));

    // TODO: Make the tab content scrollable

    return control;
}
```

As the content of the tabs contains a lot of elements (created inside `createMyFirstComposite(folder)` and `createMySecondComposite(folder)`, I want to add scrollbars to it.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**: Tried to implement `ScrolledComposite` as suggested by Greg:

```
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Control control = super.createContents(parent);

    TabFolder folder = new TabFolder((Composite) dialogArea, SWT.TOP);

    TabItem firstTab = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    firstTab.setText("Tab One");

    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(folder, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);

    // createMyFirstComposite() returns composite with controlls
    Composite body = createMyFirstComposite(folder);

    sc.setContent(body);
    sc.setMinSize(body.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    firstTab.setControl(sc);

    // second tab...

    return control;
}
```

Unfortunately there is no content inside the tab. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Use `ScrolledComposite`

Comment: @greg-449 Can you give a short example based on my code? Don't know where to put the `ScrolledComposite` inside.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScrolledComposite` and the control for the `TabItem`. Something like:

```
TabItem firstTab = new TabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);

ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(folder, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);

Composite body = // TODO create all body controls of the tab

sc.setContent(body);
sc.setMinSize(body.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

firstTab.setControl(sc);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! After changing my code by using `ScrolledComposite` I can't see no content inside my tab. Updated my question.

Comment: The argument to `createMyFirstComposite` should be the scrolled composite `sc`.